# Select unique ids that have entries over time

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame

```
 id|date      |type
  1|2017-01-03| 1
  1|2018-01-03| 1   
  1|2018-05-03| 1 
  1|2019-01-03| 1   
  1|2020-01-03| 1   
  2|2018-01-03| 1   
  2|2019-01-03| 1   
  2|2020-01-03| 1
```

I want to create a dataframe with ids that have at least 1 entry from 2017 - 2020. So in the example above, the new dataframe will only have ID 1. I tried:

```
data.groupby(["id", "date"])['type'].agg('count').reset_index()
```

This groups by the id and date and gives me count of rows per date but I am not sure how to filter from here to get those ids with consistent entries over time.

Comment: Why id 2 is not included? There's 2018-01-03. Also, what's your expected output look like?

Comment: Sorry I wanted the range to be 2017- 2020 and ID 2 does not have any entries for 2017

Comment: So do you mean having at least 1 date from each of 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020?

Comment: Yes the id needs to have a minimum of 1 row with the date 2017, 2018, 2019,2020 to be included

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the id to be returned, you can do:

```
df["year"] = df.date.apply(lambda d: d.year)
ids = df.groupby("id").agg({"year": lambda ys: set(ys) == {2017, 2018, 2019, 2020}}).query("year == True").index.to_list()
```

This will return `[1]`.

If you further need from original data frame with qualified ids, you can simply apply a filter:

```
df[df.id.isin(ids)]
```